# LoG filter on grayscale image saved as binary file

Tags: c++, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I am trying to implement a LoG filter on an image with static mask 5x5 and convolution coded in the `applyFilter()` function. However I am getting strange results, no matter what mask I apply. Saving the image without passing it through the function is working so the issue is directly here, could anyone give me any suggestions what's wrong with it?

Image is being read from dir based on dimensions passes to CLI during excecuting the script i.e. ./main 1500 1200 will open the image infile1500_1200.bin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
typedef std::vector<vec> matrix;
typedef std::vector<double> kernelRow;
typedef std::vector<kernelRow> kernel;

matrix toMatrix(const vec &flat_vec, std::size_t ncols)
{
    const auto nrows = flat_vec.size() / ncols;
    matrix mtx;
    const auto begin = std::begin(flat_vec);
    for (std::size_t row = 0; row < nrows; ++row) {
        mtx.push_back({ begin + row * ncols, begin + (row + 1)*ncols });
    }
    return mtx;
}

vec readFile(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    vec rawFileBuffer;
    std::cout << "Reading image: " << fileName << std::endl;
    inFile.open(fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t filesize = inFile.tellg();
    inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    rawFileBuffer.resize(filesize / sizeof(uint8_t));
    inFile.read((char *)rawFileBuffer.data(), filesize);
    inFile.close();
    return rawFileBuffer;
}

matrix getImageByFilename(std::string filename, int row)
{
    vec fileContent = readFile(filename);
    matrix image = toMatrix(fileContent, row);
    return image;
}

void saveImage(std::string fileName, matrix image)
{
    std::ofstream output(fileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    for (const auto &row : image)
    {
        for (const auto &col : row)
        {
            output << col;
        }
    }
    output.close();
    std::cout << "File: " << fileName << "is saved." << std::endl;
}


kernel getLogKernel()
{
    kernel kernel{
        {0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,2,1,0},
        {1,2,-16,2,1},
        {0,1,2,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0}
    };
    return kernel;
}

matrix applyFilter(matrix image, kernel filter) {
    int height = image.size();
    int width = image[0].size();
    int filterHeight = filter.size();
    int filterWidth = filter[0].size();
    matrix newImage(height, vec(width));
    int kCenterX = filterHeight / 2;
    int kCenterY = filterWidth / 2;
    std::cout << "started convolution" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            double tmp = 0;
            for (int m = 0; m < filterHeight; ++m) {
                for (int n = 0; n < filterWidth; ++n) {
                    int ii = i + (kCenterY - m);
                    int jj = j + (kCenterX - n);
                    if (ii >= 0 && ii < height && jj >= 0 && jj < width)
                        tmp += image[ii][jj] * filter[m][n];
                }
            }
            if (tmp > 255) {
                tmp = 255;
            }
            else if (tmp < 0) {
                tmp = 0;
            }
            newImage[i][j] = (uint8_t)tmp;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "convolution done" << std::endl;
    return newImage;
}

matrix getImageByFileName(std::string filename, int row)
{
    vec rawFile = readFile(filename);
    matrix image = toMatrix(rawFile, row);
    return image;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int row = atoi(argv[1]);
    int col = atoi(argv[2]);

    std::string outFile = "result" + std::string(argv[1]) + "_" + std::string(argv[2]) + ".bin";
    std::string inFile = "../labMPI/infile" + std::string(argv[1]) + "_" + std::string(argv[2]) + ".bin";

    matrix inImage = getImageByFileName(inFile, row);
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    matrix newImage = applyFilter(inImage, getLogKernel());
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << duration << "s " << std::endl;
    saveImage(outFile, newImage);

    return 0;
}
```

The input image is: 
[image: input.bin]

The result I am getting is:
[image: output.bin]

The result i obtained with flipped row/col when reading the image:
[image: correctoutput.bin]
Save image without processing gives the same image as input - so my conclusion is that saving is working OK.

Comment: Why do you have `newImage = image;`?  What happens if you use an identity filter (still 5x5, but with all zeros except for the center element which would be one)?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. You’re not posting code that we can compile and run, so it’s  it possible to reproduce the issue. From reading the code you post I cannot see any issues, likely the way that the image is read and written to file has an influence in these results. That said, there are two issues with your code that you could improve: (1) remove `mm` and `nn`, you’re reversing those indices twice, which is pointless, and (2) you cannot set all negative values to 0, those are relevant. In fact, about half the pixels in your result are expected to be negative. (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) store the output in a `int16_t` or a `float` array instead.

Comment: Actually, @1201ProgramAlarm’s comment might have hit the nail on the head. That could definitely do it. Remove that line!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however I found the issue thanks to @Szymon - it was the issue with dimensions during reading the image and transforming from 1d vector to 2d. I added the full code to my post. Somehow the col/row are flipped during reading into vector, but i have no idea why it does happen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to read the image with replaced dimensions, so shifting height with width should work.